# Многомерный массив в PHP

Tags: php

Можно ли так задать массив

```
$numbers=array(array(1,2,3),array(2,3,4),array(2,3,4))
```

и как записать цикл по всем элементам?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Наверное, так:

```
foreach($numbers as $v)
{
     foreach($v as $val)
     echo $val;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Вложенные циклы - фи!

Используйте рекурсию!

```
function walk_all($array){
    foreach ($array as $a) {
        if (is_array($a)) {
            walk_all($a);
        } else {
            echo $a." ";
        }
    }

}

$numbers=array(array(1,2,3),array(2,3,4),array(2,3,4));
walk_all($numbers);
```

Comment: @shurik, я такого же, как и вы, мнения о рекурсии в решении этой проблемы.


Там, где нет острой необходимости в ее использовании, не вижу смысла этого делать...


Чисто на заметку: кагбы у вас тоже вложенные циклы( Только "скрытые" ) И ваше решение помедленнее будет.


К чему тут **фи**, лично я не понял. Мне любопытно, вы всегда когда вам нужны вложенные циклы, используете рекурсию? Или **фи** было написано чтобы потролить?

Comment: Так или иначе вызывается цикл в цикле, через рекурсивную функцию или простым включением второго цикла в тело первого.
Рекурсия это красиво конечно но она требует включения дополнительных условий в тело функции, оно кому то нужно вообще?

Конечно для многомерных массивов, неопределенной величины этот алгоритм хорошо подходит и жертву в качестве условий внутри рекурсивной функций можно бы и заплатить.

Answer (score 2):

Так как написано выше или как-то так

```
for($i=0; $i<count($numbers); $i++) {
    for($j=0; $j<count($numbers[$i]); $j++) {
         echo $numbers[$i][$j];
    }
}
```

**UPD** Дабы не кушало память :)

```
$numbersLength = count($numbers);
for( $i=0; $i<$numbersLength; $i++ )  { 
// ++$i тоже быстрее, но это уже не принциыпиально
    $currentLength = count($number[$i]);
    for( $j=0; $j<$currentLength; $j++ ) {
         echo $numbers[$i][$j];
    }
}
```

Когда массив в цикле не изменяет своей длины лучше использовать второй вариант. Если изменяет или неизвестно - необходимо считать `$currentLength` и, возможно `$numberLength` на каждой итерации.

Comment: for($i=0; $i<count($numbers); $i++) 
Правило плохого тона делать в цикле count(). кушает память.

Comment: я вкурсе... Просто написал чтобы покороче было :)

Answer (score 1):

[`array_walk_recursive`](http://php.net/array-walk-recursive)

```
array_walk_recursive($numbers, function($val) {
    echo $val;
});
```

Comment: Стоит добавить, что этот пример будет работать с php 5.3 :)

Comment: Думал, это априори понятно :) Поскольку [PHP 5.2 уже год, как не поддерживается](http://www.php.net/archive/2010.php#id2010-12-16-1).